# IS-A relationship & HAS-A relationship in java

Tags: java

I met some confuses in java. That are

I have that questions

```
Bar IS-A Object
Foo IS-A Bar
Foo HAS-A Bar
```

Here is

```
A. class Foo extends Bar{}.
B. class Bar extends Foo{}
C. class Bar{}
D. class Foo extends Bar{Bar bar;}
```

The answer is C,D.

But A also should be answer because  **Foo IS-A Bar** is class **Foo extends Bar{}**. It is right? please explain me. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this question you have to selecty the correct signatures of the class by the provided hints.

> Bar IS-A Object

so this is definitely C.

> Foo IS-A Bar

So here Foo extends BAr.. but also notice that

> Foo HAS-A Bar

So the class Foo must have a Bar instance. So the only option is D here

Answer (score 1):

A is not an answer because of `Foo HAS-A Bar` statement.

In this question you can imagine an && between the statements. If there was an || there than A would be true too.